# Noise figure to voltage noise spectral density hand calculation

Tags: analog, noise, noise-spectral-density, low-noise-amplifier

The RF LNA of interest is the PGA-105+ from mini-circuits. From only the gain and noise figure I calculated the voltage noise spectral density that would be present at the amplifier input.

If anyone can check my calculations that would be great. My main concern is my formula for *available output noise power spectral density(input referred)* and the fact that I don't include a bandwidth in my calculations as I am looking for spectral density.

My circuit model of the amplifier is shown in the top left. The noise voltage sources are from the source impedance and the intrinsic, input referred voltage noise seen at the amp input pin.

[image]

Comment: This should help https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Hyem-Saadi/post/How-to-find-RMS-value-of-noise-voltage/attachment/5af2dc2d4cde260d15dd9472/AS%3A624339384823808%401525865517114/download/1312+-+Noise+2+-+slides.pdf

Comment: An amplifier with a noise figure F (power ratio, not dB) is equivalent to a noiseless amplifier with a noise power spectral density of (F-1)kT added at the input.  So a 1.7dB noise figure corresponds to F=1.48 so the equivalent PSD at the input is 0.48kT, or about -177dBm/Hz

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 That specific TI app note is for OP amps. This is an RF amplifier, so I can't use those equations for the most part.

Comment: @Tesla23 How would one convert Power spectral density to noise voltage spectral density? Given a impedance matched 50 ohms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An amplifier with gain \$G\$ and noise figure \$F\$ may be represented by a noiseless amplifier with gain \$G\$ and added input noise power spectral density \$N_a\$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYfxQ4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

where \$N_a = (F-1)kT_0\$

and \$F\$ is the noise figure as a power ratio:  \$F=10^{F_{dB}/10}\$

by convention, \$T_0 = 290K\$  see [HP App note](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee133/appnotes/5952-8255E.pdf) p8

You can convert this to a voltage from a source of impedance \$Z_0\$ by
$$\bar{e_n^2} = N_aZ_0$$

For your example, with a 1.7dB noise figure in a 50 ohm system,  \$F=1.48\$ , the equivalent added noise PSD is \$N_a \approx -177dBm/Hz\$ which is equivalent to an rms voltage of about \$0.31nV/\sqrt{Hz}\$ from a 50 ohm source.

Just be careful as the noise figure will, in general, vary with source impedance, so although this representation is accurate for a 50 ohm source, if you change the source impedance \$F\$ and \$N_a\$ will likely change.

Comment: Isn't it -supposed to be -177 dBm/ Hz not root-Hz?

Comment: Fixed, thanks - @MaxW

Comment: Got the device on a spectrum analyzer, the noise ended up 3 times as low as calculated.

Comment: If you are saying that the noise volts was low by a factor of 3 (about 10dB), then either you have a device with a noise figure of around 0.6dB (probably unlikely) or there is some issue with your measurement.  Happy to engage if you post more details.  How exactly are you measuring the noise?

Comment: 50 ohm terminated input to get the noise spectral density floor of the spectrum analyzer, average was 1.5nV/rtHz. Then a 50 ohm input load on an eval board of the device, output connected to spectrum analzer, RBW 10Hz. Showed a ~3nV/rtHz spectral density in the 10MHz to 100MHz region, with a 1/f looking hump from 50kHz to 10MHz.

Comment: The noise from a 50 ohm resistor at room temp is around 0.9nV/rtHz, feed that through an amplifier with 16dB of gain gives 5.6nV/rtHz.  If you are not measuring at least this then either the amplifier hasn't the gain you think, or there is a problem with how you are measuring the  noise.

Comment: I thought the same thing about the 50 ohm resistor being multiplied by the gain. However, while testing the noise spectrum, I tested the gain and phase of the amplifier, and the gain was exactly as spec'd, so I know the gain is fine. Then why wouldn't the 50 ohm be multiplied by the gain?? I sure don't know but when I did the math backwards from my test results I did end up with a negative value for the input referred noise of the LNA. What could be wrong with my test setup to have such a low output noise?

Comment: Another interesting thing is that the gain of the amplifier is <0dB below 1MHz, yet the noise spectral density below 1MHz of the device was 30-60 nV/rtHz

Comment: Is it oscillating?  It has gain up to several GHz, how far up can you check for oscillations?  What spectrum analyzer are you using?

Comment: It's not oscillating, as far as I can tell. The device is on an Eval board so it's set up pretty optimally for test. Spectrum analyzer is a FSV3 Rohde & Schwartz.

Answer (score 0):

It's in a matched system so the 50 ohm resistor noise is about 0.45 nV/rt(Hz), x gain = 2.8 nV/rt(Hz).